# SonarQube Analysis for Erlang

Tags: erlang, sonarqube

I am trying to run sonar analysis for Erlang. I have downloaded the plug-ins and with 60+ rules, it is able to tell me which part of the source code is not compliant.

However, I cannot get the SQALE rating to work correctly, in particular, the technical debt always shows 0.0 days. How do I configure this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not configurable, basically the plug-in does not support this SQALE feature. In fact, the most recent version of SonarQube does not use SQALE anymore.